# Specifying Objects in Japanese

Tags: grammar, words, usage, meaning, questions

How do you say and write 'this is' and 'that is' in Japanese? Expanding on this, how would you say and write 'these are' and 'those are'? Around this topic, are there any male and female words in Japanese? Also, How would you say 'this is/these are' and 'that is/those are' when it is relevant to people?

If someone is able to display a written version of the words, could it please be in kanji and hiragana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.... you are talking about demonstrative pronouns, correct?

This = これ
Ex: This is my book. これ（This) は ( I intentionally say nothing, however, it is a particle ), 私 ( my ) の ( also a particle ) 本 ( book ) です　( polite way of saying だ ( meaning, used for decisive endings ))

これは私の本です。

That = あれ

Ex, That is my book. You can just swap with "これ"

```
---> あれは私の本です。
```

These = これら. Just switch. These are my books.

---> これらは私の本です。（ Be reminded that unlike English, we do not specifically
distinguish plural from a singular ( There are exceptions ))

Those = 　あれら Switch. Those are my books

---> あれらは私の本です。

Unlike Russian, or other most of European countries ( except English ), we do not have
words distinguished with sex. ( basically ( meaning, females use some "special" words
when they speak )).

Thank you.